# How can I re-indent Vue.js code in VSCode?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

The title tells it all. I have installed a couple of Vue.js related plugins for Visual Studio Code, but still can not format the code, as I used to do it easily in SublimeText. 
Appreciate your hints?

Comment: Does CTRL SHIFT i not work for you? That works for me (Arch Linux, latest VS Code).

Comment: no. it does nothing. BTW, I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, it's i, not j.

Comment: still no result.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an extension called "Prettier" or "Beautify", then follow the instruction to set it up/
Just open the Extension window and look it up there, after you installed it you can right click on the opened file window and choose "Format Document" or simply press "Ctrl + Alt + F"

Comment: I have installed Beautify, but not tweaked it. When I press  `Ctrl + Shift + F` I get only search form. Also right click and `Format Document` does not indent neither html nor js part.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant "Ctrl + Alt + F", try tweak it on setting just follow the documentation

Comment: have you had vetur installed?

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + F` does nothing either. Yes, I have alos installed `vetur`, though not tweaked it either.

Comment: @Buddy vetur did very well. Thanks a lot